# java Buffered Image : Detecting black pixels

Tags: java, rgb, bufferedimage, bmp

I have this simple code to go through a 24bit color windows bmp file

```
BufferedImage mapa = BMPDecoder.read(new File("maps/map.bmp"));
    
final int xmin = mapa.getMinX();
final int ymin = mapa.getMinY();
    
final int ymax = ymin + mapa.getHeight();
final int xmax = xmin + mapa.getWidth();


for (int i = xmin;i<xmax;i++)
{
   for (int j = ymin;j<ymax;j++)
   {
                
    int pixel = mapa.getRGB(i, j);
        
    if (pixel == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("black at "+i+","+j);
    }
   }
}
```

However, when testing on a completely black image, I get this value at pixel : `-16777216`.

I was hoping to get a 0x0.

How can I test for black pixels (or any other color for that reason) ?

## update

Im testing against `((pixel & 0xff) == 0)`. Is this right?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`-16777216` is `0xFF000000` in hexadecimal, corresponding to opaque black.

Addendum: Looking at your update, I'd think you want `((pixel & 0x00FFFFFF) == 0)` as your predicate.