# analyzing image file for black spots

Tags: java, .net, image, analysis

I'm writing a program that will scan an image file for dark spots. It needs to gather some information about the size and amount of the spots. The images are always black and white and of a piece of metal. Does anyone recommend an api or existing tool for something like this? I'd prefer java or .net but feel free to suggest anything.

Comment: Can you include a (small) sample image?  If you don't have the rep. to embed one in your question, upload it to an image sharing site & provide a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the black spots are all having the same RGB value for black, this will only require opening the image and counting the black pixels and dividing by the total number of pixels in the image. for reading an image and detecting black pixels, you can find info here:

[java-buffered-image-detecting-black-pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539670/java-buffered-image-detecting-black-pixels)

please note that another way to open the image (in the previous link) would be:

```
BufferedImage mapa = ImageIO.read(file);
```

If your spots are composed of different RGB that look black/dark , then you might find an answer in the following post: (it deals with green spots but you can easily use the methods mentioned and look for black spots)

[how-to-calculate-the-amount-of-green-spots-in-an-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204256/how-to-calculate-the-amount-of-green-spots-in-an-image)

Comment: Thanks for the links... it got me going. My situation was slightly different but I ended up using a custom look up table to map colors of a certain shade and darker to pure black and map any color below that thresh hold to pure white. Then it was a 2 color image and I could calculate the black spots. Thank you.